# Adding menu with categories on header

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.6

I trying to add the categories of my store in the header, for this I do these steps:

On page.xml, add this block categories:

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
      <block type="core/template" name="top.categories" as="topCategories" template="catalog/navigation/categories.phtml" />
      ...
</block>
```

Create the categories.phtml, on catalog/navigation/, with this code:

```
<?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(1,'level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<nav class="left-nav">
    <ul class="nav-list">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
<?php endif ?>
```

And call this block in header, with the code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topCategories') ?>
```

But, whe I call this, return a error:

> a:5:{i:0;s:111:"Invalid method
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template::renderCategoriesMenuHtml(Array (
>       [0] => 1
>       [1] => level-top ) )";i:1;s:3818:"#0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('renderCategorie...', Array)

I'm using Magento 1.6.2.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block that you are calling with `categories.phtml` should implement `renderCategoriesMenuHtml` method, that should return menu items. You are using `core/template` block, which doesn't have such method (and shouldn't). You have to use correct block type, that implements getting categories html.

Try to use `catalog/navigation` instead of `core/template`.

Comment: What error does it show now? If the same one, try to flush your cache